# Cycle2 image categories

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I created a gallery with the help of cycle2 carousel plugin and I need a category that is why I write ul.li element on my carousel and when I clicked one category related images must be open and another image must be invisible how can I do that ? I wrote a jquery but doesn't work.

[and click to see on codepen - correctly](http://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/dvozjx)

here you are my code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  $(".filter li").on("click", function() {
    var activeId = $(this).attr("id");

    $("img[data-id]").hide();
    $("img[data-id = '" + activeId + "']").show();
  });
});
```

```css
.cycle-slideshow {
  position: relative;
  width: 800px;
  height: 494px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#single-pager a img {
  width: 49.3px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

#single-pager a.cycle-pager-active img {
  opacity: 0.4;
}

#single-left,
#single-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 1000;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
  padding: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#single-left {
  left: 0;
}

#single-right {
  right: 0;
}

.filter {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  right: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  color: #FFF;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  padding: 10px 30px;
}

.filter li {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.cycle2/2.1.6/jquery.cycle2.min.js"></script>

<div class="cycle-slideshow" data-cycle-pager="#single-pager" data-cycle-pager-template="<a href='#'><img src='{{src}}' width=48 height=48></a>" data-cycle-prev="#single-left" data-cycle-next="#single-right" data-cycle-pause-on-hover="true" data-cycle-auto-height="true">
  <img src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/golden-wheat-field-lightbox.jpg" data-id="sports">
  <img src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/sunny-day-lightbox.jpg" data-id="naturel">
  <img src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/night-in-the-city-lightbox.jpg" data-id="animals">
  <img src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/sakura%20trees-lightbox.jpg" data-id="animals" />
  <img src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/daffodil-flowers-lightbox.jpg" data-id="animals" />
  <img src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/dandelion-lightbox.jpg" data-id="animals" />
  <img src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/tulips-lightbox.jpg" data-id="sports" />
  <ul class="filter">
    <li id="sports">Sports</li>
    <li id="naturel">Naturel</li>
    <li id="animals">Animals</li>
  </ul>
  <div id="single-next-prev">
    <span id="single-left">Prev</span>
    <span id="single-right">Next</span>
  </div>

</div>

<div id="single-pager" class="center external"></div>
```

Comment: Store all the images in array and rebuild the html and initialize plugin programmatically again each time

Comment: how will I do that any example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this might be a little bit late, but you need på reinitialize the slider when you use the "filter"-function.

I have also put all your images in an array so you have control over the in the code.

Check out the code below for a solution

```js
var images = [
  {
      cat: "sports",
      src: "https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/golden-wheat-field-lightbox.jpg"
  },
    {
        cat: "naturel",
        src: "https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/sunny-day-lightbox.jpg"
    },
    {
        cat: "animals",
        src: "https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/night-in-the-city-lightbox.jpg"
    },
    {
        cat: "animals",
        src: "https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/sakura%20trees-lightbox.jpg"
    },
    {
        cat: "animals",
        src: "https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/daffodil-flowers-lightbox.jpg"
    },
    {
        cat: "animals",
        src: "https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/dandelion-lightbox.jpg"
    },
    {
        cat: "sports",
        src: "https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/tulips-lightbox.jpg"
    }
]

$(document).ready(function () {
    for (var i in images) {
        $("#mySlideshow").append("<img src='" + images[i].src + "'/>");
    }

    init()

    $(".filter li").on("click",
        function() {
            $("#mySlideshow").cycle('destroy');
            $("#mySlideshow img").remove();

            var activeId = $(this).attr("id");

            buildCycleSlideshow(activeId);
        })
})

function init() {
    $("#mySlideshow").cycle({
        log: false,
        pauseOnHover: true,
        next: "#single-right",
        prev: "#single-left",
        autoHeight: true,
        pager: "#single-pager",
        pagerTemplate: "<a href='#'><img src='{{src}}' width=48 height=48></a>"
    });
}

function buildCycleSlideshow(id) {
    var showAllImages = false;

    if (id == "allImages") {
        showAllImages = true;
    }
    

    for (var i in images) {
        if (images[i].cat == id || showAllImages) {
            $("#mySlideshow").append("<img src='" + images[i].src + "'/>");
        }
    }
    init();
}
```

```css
#mySlideshow {
  position: relative;
  width: 800px;
  height: 494px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#single-pager a img {
  width: 49.3px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

#single-pager a.cycle-pager-active img {
  opacity: 0.4;
}

#single-left,
#single-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 1000;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
  padding: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#single-left {
  left: 0;
}

#single-right {
  right: 0;
}

.filter {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  right: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  color: #FFF;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  padding: 10px 30px;
}

.filter li {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.cycle2/2.1.6/jquery.cycle2.min.js"></script>

<div id="mySlideshow">
  <ul class="filter">
    <li id="sports">Sports</li>
    <li id="naturel">Naturel</li>
    <li id="animals">Animals</li>
    <li id="allImages">Show all images</li>
  </ul>
  <div id="single-next-prev">
    <span id="single-left">Prev</span>
    <span id="single-right">Next</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="single-pager" class="center external"></div>
```

Comment: oow thanks..this is the another example (http://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/VpvLNp) with html but there is something that I couldn't achive to show all image and thank you so much again for your helps

Comment: This is your solution with the `Show all images`: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Vpvzrg

Comment: can I ask another question that I wonder..we have images array can we use without array ? is there any way using with html dynamically?

Comment: I am building the HTML dynamically with the array. The problem is that you need to rebuild and reinit the library when you change group. It will be complicated to do if you have all the images in HTML.